# How to invoke onclick event on select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-select2

I am trying to bind onclick to select input element with select2 initialization.

I want to bind a handler when the drop-down is clicked or focused.

```
<select class="form-control" id="type" name="type" required="required">
    <option value="breakfast" <?= ($type == 'breakfast')? 'selected' : '';?>>Breakfast</option>
    <option value="snacks" <?= ($type == 'snacks')? 'selected' : '';?>>Snacks</option>
</select>
```

Here's the js part:

```
$('#type').select2({}).on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
    console.log('not working');
});
```

I also tried "`select2-open/opening`" but to no avail.
How do I make the event binding work?

Comment: What is the version that you're using ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I'm using 3.5.1 version

Comment: @Harish wouldn't be posting if this had worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the version 3.5.1 you're using, you should use `select2-selecting` instead of `select2:selecting` like :

```
$('#type').select2({}).on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
    console.log('not working');
});
```

```js
$('#type').select2({});

$('#type').on("select2-opening", function(e) {
  console.log('Opening');
});
$('#type').on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
  console.log('Selecting');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.1/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.1/select2.min.js"></script>
<select style="width:300px" id="type">
  <option value="CA">California</option>
  <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
  <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
  <option value="WA">Washington</option>
</select>
```

Comment: worked.. but I'm pretty sure it was `select2-selecting' before I updated it to `select2:selecting`.. anyway it is working now.. thanks

Answer (score 3):

For Version 4.0 + you can use below.

```
$('#yourselect').on("select2:select", function(e) { 
   // what you would like to happen
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I opted for just using the jquery event 'change', seems to behave as expected.

```
    $('#fieldListSelect').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select a field'
        }).on("change", function (e) 
        {
            var key = $('#fieldListSelect option:selected').text();
            var value = $('#fieldListSelect').val();

            $('#result').html("key : " + key + ", value : " + value);
    });
```